# Unable to set the correct MIME type when slicing a blob

Tags: javascript, blob, slice, mime-types

I experienced a bug where svg images could not be shown on Safari. After investigating I realized it was due to the fact that I load ressources as packs/archives of files that I split in the browser.

When I load the ressources, I get a plain text blob. I use [blob.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/slice) to extract a ressource, passing the correct MIME type. However, it seems that the new blob does not have the correct MIME type but still the old one (plain text). On Chrome and Firefox, it turns out that the image can be displayed even if its MIME type is incorrect but not on Safari.

Here is the code which does not work:

```
const blob = new Blob([ressource], {
  type: "text/plain",
});

const slicedBlob = blob.slice(0, blob.size, "image/svg+xml"); 
// slicedBlob.type is "text/plain"
```

I also reproduced some minimal test cases: https://jsbin.com/yavaxadalo/edit?js,output

From the MDN docs and the [W3C specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#slice-method-algo) it looks that I use the method as it is intended too, but maybe I am missing something ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have to admit I am a bit clueless about this Safari's bug.
This should probably be [reported](https://webkit.org/reporting-bugs/).

I'd like to point out that your jsbin was a bit misleading, since the Blob returned by the slice method correctly has its `type` set to `'image/svg+xml'` (you were logging the type of the original `blob2`), but this just makes things even weirder...

Now, I'm not too clear as to why you want to use Blob.slice here, if you just want to change the type of that Blob, then you can simply create a new one using the `Blob()` constructor which also accepts other Blobs as *blobType*.

```js
const blob1 = new Blob([
`<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect width="100" height="100"/>
</svg>`
], {type: 'text/plain'});
console.log(blob1.type);

const blob2 = new Blob([blob1], {type: 'image/svg+xml'});
console.log(blob2.type);
img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob2);
```

```html
<img id="img">
```

And if you really wish to use the Blob.slice method, then as a workaround, you can create a new one from the Blob constructor which will wrap it correctly:

```js
const blob1 = new Blob([
`<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect width="100" height="100"/>
</svg>[BAD-DATA]`
], {type: 'text/plain'});

// if we need to slice it
const sliced = blob1.slice(0, blob1.size - '[BAD-DATA]'.length);
// wrap it again for Safari...
const blob2 = new Blob([sliced], {type: 'image/svg+xml'});
img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob2);
```

```html
<img id="img">
```

Comment: You are right about the error in my jsbin, thanks. About the usage of `blob.slice()`, that's because the blob may contain many assets (which may not be of the same type) and not only one like in my test case. About the `new Blob([blob])`, thanks for the advice, this is much simpler than my attempt using a FileReader.